# SetProperty not working correctly on the "Text" property of an editable ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox, prism

Summary:

I have an editable ComboBox where the user can select a "Connection" object from the list, or they can type in the URL for a new Connection object.  If I use the "Prism way" for binding the Text property of the editable ComboBox, it doesn't put the typed value into the property that I'm binding to.  If I use the old INotifyPropertyChanged way, the typed in value gets correctly populated into the bound property.

MODEL:

```
public class Connection : BindableBase
{
    private string _url = "";
    private string _username = "";
    private string _password = "";

    public string URL
    {
        get { return _url; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _url, value); }
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _username, value); }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _password, value); }
    }

    public Connection() { }

    public Connection(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        URL = url;
        UserName = username;
        Password = password;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _url;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Connections, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" 
                    IsEditable="True" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConnection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedConnection.URL, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
BindingList<Connection> _connections = new BindingList<Connection>(); public BindingList<Connection> Connections { get { return _connections; } set { SetProperty(ref _connections, value); } }
```

ViewModel binding that works:

```
    public Connection SelectedConnection
    {
        get { return _selectedConnection; }
        set
        {
            _selectedConnection = value;
            if (_selectedConnection == null) _selectedConnection = new Connection();
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedConnection");
        }
    }
```

ViewModel binding that does not work using Prism:

```
    public Connection SelectedConnection
    {
        get { return _selectedConnection; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedConnection, value);
            if (_selectedConnection == null) _selectedConnection = new Connection();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SetProperty` is raising `PropertyChanged` if a new value is set, setting `_selectedConnection` doesn't, of course.

The equivalent of

```
public Connection SelectedConnection
{
    get => _selectedConnection;
    set
    {
        _selectedConnection = value ?? new Connection();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedConnection));
    }
}
```

using `SetProperty` is this:

```
public Connection SelectedConnection
{
    get { return _selectedConnection; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _selectedConnection, value ?? new Connection());
    }
}
```